# How to modify active record query result attribute value in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am having query

```
@users = User.all
```

`@users` contains name, created_at, email, mobile etc as attribute values

I want to update the created at to user readable format from mysql datetime format and update it in controller

I have written the code to convert date to human readable format but don't know how to set value to the attribute before it goes to view

So any method will be appriciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strftime()` directly on the `created_at` attribute in the view:

```
@user.created_at.strftime("%D")
```

Docs: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime

Comment: This is what I call a Pragmatic answer, no need to define a helper, or  an extra method in a model.

Comment: @rorra: in a real application I'd still advocate a helper method. See comments under my answer :)

Comment: in a real world app i would refactor your code to a simple strftime call ;)

Comment: Why use strftime when rails provides a to_s override?

Comment: As I said below and also because strftime is lower level. But yeah I take your point if the formatting is going to be required in several places.

Answer (score 3):

Rails can add additional date/time formats... put something like this in an initializer file:

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:short_date] = "%b %d, %Y"
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:short_slashed] = "%m/%d/%Y" #careful when giving this to mysql adapter
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:date_dashed] = "%m-%d-%Y"
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:mysql_date] = "%Y-%m-%d"
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:full_date] = "%A, %B %d, %Y"
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:short_slashed] = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p"
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:mytime] = "%a %b %d at %I:%M %p"
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:short_date] = "%b %d, %Y"
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:date_dashed] = "%m-%d-%Y"
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:mysql_date] = "%Y-%m-%d"
```

and then in your view, you can choose any of them:

```
 @user.created_at.to_s(:mytime) 
 @user.created_at.to_s(:short_date)
```

[documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/to_s)

Comment: Yeah this is cool. I favour using strftime if the formatting is only required once in the app as it keeps things simple, but this is definitely handy for larger apps

Answer (score 2):

Messing with attribute values just for the sake of presentation - bad idea, don't do that.

This looks like a helper method. I'd probably put it into User model itself (`make_human_date` contains your logic of "humanizing" the date, which you haven't specified)

```
# model
class User
  def human_created_at
    make_human_date(created_at)
  end
end

# view
<%= @user.human_created_at %>
```

Alternatively, you can make a real helper method, because it only aids presentation, it's not part of business logic.

```
# helper
module MyControllerHelper
  def human_created_at user
    make_human_date(user.created_at)
  end
end

# view
<%= human_created_at(@user) %>
```

Comment: Just wondering, why create all this extra code when Ruby provides the `strftime()` method on DateTime to perform essentially the same function?

Comment: It's not specified exactly what kind of humanization the OP does. Maybe `strftime` will cut it, maybe it won't. This is the general case.

Comment: Hard to see in which case `strftime` wouldn't be enough, or another humanization helper already included in rails. This is definitely not worthy of a model method either IMO.

Comment: Don't underestimate the fluidity of business requirements. Helper method abstracts this. It can also handle localization, etc. Model method - it's my choice of taste. Helper method is where this should belong. IMHO.

Comment: Using a to_s override as explained below puts the semantic definition in one common place, but lets each view determine its own flavor... best of both worlds!